# setDataValue is not a function after calling sequelize findAll method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm looking to create a new property after the [sequelize `findAll`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html) method.

by using this method

`setDataValue`

And im getting

> setDataValue is not a function

https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-setDataValue

[image]

**post.controller.js**

```
 getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        { model: models.Likes }
      ],
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: 6
    }).then(posts => {
      posts.setDataValue('test', 'hoot')
      res.json(posts);
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `posts` is an array, not a single object, so you can't call `setDataValue()` on it. If you want a single result use `findOne()` or `findByPk()`.

Loop over the array to access each instance that is returned to access `setDataValue()`. Alternatively use `raw: true` in your query to return raw JSON objects which you can set keys on, if the intent is to return as JSON this will be more performant.

Since you are using async/await you should also avoid thenables. Try the following:

```
getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  // use async/await here
  const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
      { model: models.Likes }
    ],
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    limit: 6,
    // uncomment this line to return raw JSON objects instead of Model Instances
    // raw: true,
  });

  // loop over each post in the array and convert t
  posts.forEach((post) => post.setDataValue('test', 'hoot'));

  // return result
  // note that you probably want to call post.toJSON() 
  // or add raw: true to your query
  return res.json(posts);
},
```

Comment: will five this a shot, and let you know how it went.Thank you so much .